# Map enum to float value

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a enum.

```
public enum EventRange{ oneHour=1,oneHourThirtyMinutes
}
```

Now lets say for 1 hour I want get 1 and for oneHourThirtyMinutes I want to get 1.5

How can I achieve this in dotnet core ?

Comment: You can ether use a conversion method that take the enum as a parameter and return a float or use custom attributes to store the date you want. For custom attributes check the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/creating-custom-attributes)

Comment: An enum is essentially a label for an int. You can pass an `EventRange` value anywhere an int is expected. You don't even have to cast it. You can use [any integral type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types) as the [base for an enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum) as the base of an enum, eg `enum ErrorCode : ushort { ...}`

Comment: Any reason you can't just use a `TimeSpan` for this and allow any time range (assuming this is one)? If necessary you can test if it's divisible by a specific number of minutes if it shouldn't be too granular. Using an `enum` for this seems pointlessly restrictive even if you do (for now) decide that people should only have a limited choice of durations, which could also be achieved by having a specific list of them.

Comment: Why not use that value as minutes, instead of (half) hours? so 60 and 90

Comment: What's the usage/purpose of this enum? Is it to restrict options in some way? Would a dictionary<string, float> work in the same context if so?

Comment: My business says It will have a  list of specific dropdown items. So I thought that way.

Comment: I will re think about it. thank you for your suggestion

Comment: Easiest would be to simply get the Ticks of the timespan and use that for the enum. Ticks is always a long integer and can represent any date or timespan you want.

Comment: If this is just for a drop down then it feels like you should just create a map using a dictionary or something between the display value (presumably string) and actual desired value (presumably TimeSpan). Trying to map to float just means you will presumably have another conversion later between float and the time span you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Another way would be to create a lookup function

```
public enum EventRange
{
    zero,
    oneHour, 
    oneHourThirtyMinutes,
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static float GetHours(this EventRange range)
    {
        switch (range)
        {
            case EventRange.zero:
                return 0f;
            case EventRange.oneHour:
                return 1f;
            case EventRange.oneHourThirtyMinutes:
                return 1.5f;
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException($"{range} value not supported.");
        }
    }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float time = EventRange.oneHourThirtyMinutes.GetHours();
    }
}
```

---

and alternative which is better for maintenance of code is to create a custom attribute to apply the values of the enum, similar to how the `DescriptionAttribute()` works.

```
public class EventTimeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public EventTimeAttribute(float time) : base()
    {
        Time = time;
    }

    public float Time { get; }
}

public enum EventRange
{
    [EventTime(0)] zero,
    [EventTime(1f)] oneHour, 
    [EventTime(1.5f)] oneHourThirtyMinutes,
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static float GetHours(this EventRange range)
    {
        FieldInfo field = typeof(EventRange).GetField(range.ToString());
        if (field != null)
        {
            var attribute = field.GetCustomAttribute<EventTimeAttribute>();
            if (attribute != null)
            {
                return attribute.Time;
            }
        }
        throw new NotSupportedException($"{range} value not supported.");
    }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float time = EventRange.oneHourThirtyMinutes.GetHours();
    }
}
```

This method can easily be extended to support `TimeSpan` instead of `float` for time.

Comment: Imagine this train of thought: "So we need to let the user select between a static set of durations... Oh I know, let's use reflection for this!" What has this profession come to, if things like this are acceptable?

Comment: There is this German saying "Firing at sparrows with cannons" to mock overkill problem solving. This solution is more like  building a trebuchet to haul cannons at sparrows and each cannon will of course fire mid-air just for show.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride - using attributes with `enum` values is pretty standard fare in C# development. Especially when the `enum` interfaces with the UI and it is not used for calculations. Granted C# is lacking a bit here since other languages are better at associating values to enum fields, but the above solution is a good compromise between usability (extension method) and maintainability (values next to the fields).

Answer (score 3):

Get the ticks for each timespan you want to represent like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(new TimeSpan(1, 30, 0).Ticks);
```

You can now assign it to your enum:

```
enum EventRange : long 
{
    oneHourThirtyMinutes = 54000000000,
/* ... */
}
```

And convert it back like that

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan((long)EventRange.oneHourThirtyMinutes);
```

Comment: It looks like OP needs a resolution of 1 minute max (probably more like 30 minutes). So if you change your enum `int` values to `60`, `90`, etc you could then use `TimeSpan.FromMinutes((int)enumValue).` This has the maintenance benefit that devs don't have to figure out the tick value of durations first.

Answer (score -3):

Technically you could have the compiler reinterpret (*not cast*) any `float` as an `int` like so:

```cs
float f = 1.5f;
int i = *(int*)&f; // i = 1069547520
```

This of course also works the other way around and even for enum values (which are just `int`s, really):

```cs
public enum EventRange {
    OneHour = 1065353216,
    OneHourThirtyMinutes = 1069547520
}

var e = EventRange.OneHourThirtyMinutes;
float f = *(float*)&e; // f = 1.5f

// nicer notation as mentioned in the comments
f = Unsafe.As<EventRange, float>(ref e);
```

Your friends and family will shun you for this, though. The number of down-votes this answer will receive should give you an impression.

Comment: You could have least gone for style points: `int e = (int) EventRange.OneHourThirtyMinutes; float f = Unsafe.As<int, float>(ref e);`. This remains an abuse of an `enum`, of course.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks, updated. But I scrapped that rather unstylish `(int)` cast ^^